# bundle.js included twice in webpack generated index.html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

My webpack 4 generates index.html in build folder and the bundle.js is included twice in the generated index.html.

Folder structure

```
ui > 
   webpack.config.js
   index.html
   build >
         index.html
         bundle.js
```

**ui --> index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="App">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

**webpack generated index.html under build folder**

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="App">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <script src=build/rapido-web.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/rapido-web.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Any idea why bundle.js included twice

Comment: Remove manual reference to the bunde.js from your index.html. HtmlWebpackPlugin injects bundle to the thml out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the manual reference to the `bunde.js` from your index.html. `HtmlWebpackPlugin` injects bundle to the html out of the box

Comment: Thanks for your answer Honza. If you feel my question is valid kindly do upvote.